# get WinXP/Vista/7/8 startup folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

This works on Win7/8, but not on XP, why ?

```
// uses shlobj;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(Folder: Integer; CanCreate: Boolean): string;

// Gets path of special system folders
//
// Call this routine as follows:
// GetSpecialFolderPath (CSIDL_PERSONAL, false)
//        returns folder as result
//
var
   FilePath: array [0..255] of char;

begin
 SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, @FilePath[0], FOLDER, CanCreate);
 Result := FilePath;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   memo1.Lines.Add('path:|'+GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_ALTSTARTUP, false)+'|')
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried on more than one XP machine?

Comment: on win8 tried, on xp too in virtual machine

Comment: replaced to this, works fine now on all systems: CSIDL_STARTUP

Comment: When you say something "doesn't work", it's very useful for you to explain what "doesn't work" means. Does it cause an error? Does it not return the right result? Does it cause your computer to crash and start smoking? Does it show a dialog saying "I'm on strike"? Please remember we can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, and be **specific** with your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, another CSIDL might work, but it returns a different folder. It would have helped if you specified which folder you would actually need. [The MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx) has a whole list of other CSIDLs that may 'work' too, but they all return something different.

Comment: That's the *alternate startup folder*, whatever that means. If you want the user startup folder, CSIDL_STARTUP is fine.

Answer (score 1):

0..255 is too small. Use the `MAX_PATH` constant.

In Vista this folder doesn't exist anymore. I don't know what it returns (a value for backwards compatibility), but apparently it's shorter that 255 characters in Vista.

Comment: Unfortunately. Still, it's important to make the buffer large enough.

Answer (score 1):

change this CSIDL_ALTSTARTUP to this CSIDL_STARTUP

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid coding such common needs.

I use this function from JCL : [JclSysInfo.GetPersonalFolder](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aGetPersonalFolder);